# How to flip this equation on a graph

Tags: graphing-functions

$x^2+y^2=x^{(\sqrt\pi)}$
I was messing around on desmos, and graphed this and cannot figure out how to flip it over the x axis. Appreciate the help

Comment: What do you mean with "flip it over the x-axis"?

Comment: Instead of the two main points being (0,0) and (1,0) I want it to be (0,0) and (-1,0) to make it look like an infinite symbol

Comment: What is the point of this question?  Just some random equation and just some random transformation?

Comment: Yes? What is wrong with that? I'm just looking for help, I don't really know that much about math in this field

Comment: Replace $x$ with $-x$ in the equation. Incidentally, I’d describe this as reflecting in the $y$-axis, not the $x$-axis.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but that doesn't work. It completely changes the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of the two main points being (0,0) and (1,0) I want it to be (0,0) and (0,-1).

Ah that's simple.

**how to do that**

If you exchange the x with the - you get the graph rotated $90^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise (this is always the case). This is because $+y$ is a  $90^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise rotated $+x$.:

$ y^{2} + x^{2} = y^{\sqrt{\pi}} $  is $ y^{2} + x^{2}  = x^{\sqrt{\pi}} $ but rotated $90^{\circ}$ counter-clockwise.

If you now multiply all $y$ by $-1$, the graph that you rotated $90^{\circ}$ counterclockwise now rotates $180^{\circ}$ counterclockwise (this is always the case too). This is because we use it to mirror the therm about the x-axis.

$ (-y)^{2} + x^{2} = y^{2} + x^{2} = (-y)^{\sqrt{\pi}} $  is $ y^{2} + x^{2}  = x^{\sqrt{\pi}} $ but rotated $90^{\circ}$ clockwise.

**soluton**

Aka you're soluton is $ y^{2} + x^{2} = (-y)^{\sqrt{\pi}} $

The plot of this $ y^{2} + x^{2} = (-y)^{\sqrt{\pi}} $:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7wow.png]

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help